# How to extract text from tags using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have following XML file:

```
<class id="1" name="good/bad">
    <verb>
        <token>like</token>
        <token>feel</token>
    </verb>
    <mess>This is <sugg>not</sugg> text</mess>
    <id type="incorrect">I'm glad to <marker>unsee you</marker>.</id>
    <id type="correct">I'm glad to see you.</id>
</class>
```

I need to extract text from a specific tag. On http://effbot.org are very few examples and generally poor documentation. Maybe there are good examples somewhere else? And how process the text in the same tags (token) as separate entities? Thanks in advance! The result should be approximately as follows:

```
(like) feel > not #This is not text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear on what you wish to do with the contents of the `<mess>` element.
For the children of the `<verb>` element, try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
the_tree = ET.fromstring('''<class id="1" name="good/bad">
    <verb>
        <token>like</token>
        <token>feel</token>
    </verb>
    <mess>This is <sugg>not</sugg> text</mess>
    <id type="incorrect">I'm glad to <marker>unsee you</marker>.</id>
    <id type="correct">I'm glad to see you.</id>
</class>''')
elems = the_tree.find('./verb').getchildren()
verbs = [verb.text for verb in elems]
# -> ['like', 'feel']
```

---

If your file is larger, perhaps you would prefer this alternative way of accessing elements:

```
tree, id_map = ET.XMLID('''<class id="1" name="good/bad">
    <verb>
        <token>like</token>
        <token>feel</token>
    </verb>
    <mess>This is <sugg>not</sugg> text</mess>
    <id type="incorrect">I'm glad to <marker>unsee you</marker>.</id>
    <id type="correct">I'm glad to see you.</id>
</class>''')
elems = id_map['1'].find('verb')
verbs = [verb.text for verb in elems]
```

Comment: I wish to get both texts as separated objects.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. But I want to get like and feel as independent objects. That's issue.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the clarification. You could store them in a list. I altered the example code to do just that.

Comment: Hm. It makes sense. Thank you. I'll try my best to go forward.